# ModuleNotFoundError makemigrations,migrate o runserver Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-urls

Hola tengo un problema al querer ejecutar makemigrations o migrate o runserver.

El detalle se encuentre en que tengo una app recien creada que se llama avisodeprivacidad, la tengo en INSTALLED_APPS pero al darle makemigrations me marca "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'avisodeprivacidad**servicios**'. Por lo que veo el sistema le esta agregando un servicios al final de la app. También tengo otra app que se llama servicios no se si este afectando la otra app.

Este es mi models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

# Create your models here.
class AvisoPrivacidad(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Titulo')
    contenido = RichTextField(verbose_name='Contenido')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de creación')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Fecha de edición')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Aviso de Privacidad"
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Y este el error completo que me marca en la terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\Jorge\Programacion Python\APPS DJANGO\odontofacil2\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\Jorge\Programacion Python\APPS DJANGO\odontofacil2\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 178, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'avisodeprivacidadservicios'
```

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final lo solucione en INSTALLED_APPS me faltaba poner la coma en la app estaba de esta manera:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ***
    'avisodeprivacidad'
    ***
]
```

y le puse la coma al final:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ***
    'avisodeprivacidad',
    ***
]
```